# Post request using Volley always throws server error in Android with Laravel backend

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing an Android app. I am making api request using Volley. But whenever I make post request, it always throws server error with stats code 500. But I am pretty sure, the url really exists and return 200 status code when I use some tools like fiddler or rest client of chrome extension.

But when I make request from genny motion emulator, it return http 500 status.

This is how I make request:

```
public void submitLogin(String email,String password)
    {
        try{
            String url = getResources().getString(R.string.api_end_point)+"auth/login";
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject("{\"email\":\""+email+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\"}");
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, jsonParam, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //tvErrorMessage.setText("Network error encountered");
                }
            });

            VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tvErrorMessage.setText("Internal error encountered with application");
        }
    }
```

I already set internet permission in manifest file. This is my first post request. But I successfully made get requests before. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found error with my code. First of all, I am sorry for incomplete tags and question. That was an error with Laravel.Normally laravel filter request by csrf middleware. So I just need to remove csrf middle from filtering my api request in route.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your url to request is wrong.

Can you post the url?

Try remove the "\" from parameters.

Comment: Url exists and I havnt implement logic yet in function of server side. It is empty totally catching post request. I am using laravel 5.2 for server side. I tried your one and it is not working